# running a process within docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I use libreoffice to convert a word document to a pdf document.
The process for this is soffice.exe or the equivalent in linux.

This process is usually located at: c:\program files\libreoffice\program\soffice.exe

It perfectly works when running the application in iisexpress, but not withing docker.

I assume I need to open up an entry because docker needs access?

code snippet:

```
//convert word to pdf
                var convert = new ReportGenerator(LibreOfficeOptions.LibreOfficeWindows);
                convert.Convert(RootPath + viewModel.Invoices.First().InvoiceId + ".docx", RootPath + viewModel.Invoices.First().InvoiceId + ".pdf");
                Log.Information($"Invoice word document has been converted to pdf document!");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Exception has been thrown in the creation of the invoice final document: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: is it installed within your container? what is your base image?

Comment: no libre office is installed on my computer not docker currently docker desktop. my base image is .net 5.0 sdk or whatever visual studio takes as image

Comment: @DanielA.White can I just use a volume and put the outside program there?

Comment: the base image is a linux one - so you couldn't mount a windows volume and run that.

Comment: @DanielA.White thats true but in production it will be linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write OS based conditions here to use the corresponding libreoffice binary.

1. In your code, detect current OS and set process path and doc path corresponding to the OS detected. Binary path and path separators differ in Windows (`\`)  and Unix (`/`)
2. Add steps to install libreoffice in your `dockerfile` for final image. [Libreoffice Dockerfile](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/online/tree/docker/Debian). If you have your own private repository, you can create your own custom docker image for dotnet runtime to include libreoffice to avoid increase in project build times. This comes with an additional maintenance of updating custom docker images regularly as soon as patches are out.

Comment: thanks for the information , i'll look into it. currently I have setup a volume and it does work it can call the soffice.exe file in this case but it does fail after.